# MonthCalendar don't have Click Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, click, double-click, monthcalendar

I can't find Click event(picture1) in vs2008 . but the MSDN have Click event (picture2). why?

picure1:

[image]

picure2:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The click event is marked with `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]` which means that it won't show up in the properties box. The reason for this is because it's not designed to called directly from your code. From `MonthCalendar.Click's` [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.click.aspx):

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code.

There's more information about the `BrowsableAttribute` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx).

Comment: Thank a lot  for KeyboardP ! Now i had known this reason. I have a new question：  "not use directly "－－ How do i use this event ?

Comment: You don't; you are strongly encouraged not to. Would MouseDown or MouseUp provide what you need?

Comment: I need is MonthCalendar.DoubleClick(). I want to provide two kinds operation for select date. One: click OK button . Two: if user double click the MonthCalendar, then return the selected date.

Comment: You can create your own double-click method as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498014/capture-doubleclick-for-monthcalendar-control-in-windows-forms-app

Comment: Thanks for roken,KeyboardP. My understanding is as follow: MonthCalendar don't complete  DoubleClick() as  inherited Control. So you only design for it .

Comment: Yes, it's only there to ensure consistency in the framework. You have to either avoid double-clicking or implement it yourself.